# How to add the sidebar to all the pages except the home page?

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development, themes, html5

I am creating a theme and I need some idea to create a below structure on my all the page
except on the home page.

[image]

I know how to create a menu, sidebar, footer, and call dynamically on the page.
My issue is, In which file do I have to edit it in my theme so that it will not affect on the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but probably in the file which calls `get_sidebar()`:

You could do something like

```
if ( ! is_home() ) {
    get_sidebar();
}
```

Or in your header.php where the main-element starts (which probably wraps the sidebar). You could give it a class if the page is not the home page:

```
<!-- body and header-stuff -->

<main class="<?php echo is_home() ? 'home-without-sidebar' : 'with-sidebar'; ?>">

<!-- other stuff -->

<?php
    if ( ! is_home() ) {
        get_sidebar();
    }
?>
```

And then define CSS accordingly:

```
.home-without-sidebar {
    /* whatever properties */
}
.with-sidebar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20rem 1fr;
    /* more properties here */
}
```

Comment: Let me try your answer

Comment: Yes, It's working. Thank you for the help